# Exchange 2010 and office 365 email synchronization

Tags: office-365, exchange-server

We are currently using Exchange 2010 for our organization emails and now plan to migrate to office365.

We want to keep our local Exchange server synchronized with office365 exchange server after the migration (i.e. After completion of migration process, MX record points to office365 but the emails received at office365 are synchronized/forwarded to local exchange server as well).

1: Is it possible with active directory synchronization enabled?

2: Is it possible without active directory synchronization enabled?